# I want to remove some photos from iPhone 4s but keep them all in Photo Stream & iCloud

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, photo-stream

I want to remove some photos from iPhone but keep them in Photos & iCloud. I want to keep my photoson my Mac Air, & desktop. When I try to delete them off my phone it tells me it will be delated from Photostream & iCloud.

I just want to decrease the number of photos on my iPhone. I connected to computer to upload some but it didn't ask me if I wanted to remove any from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear, but I'll take a guess.

If you connect the phone to a computer and no photos are removed when you sync, the most likely setup is the iPhone is using iCloud Photo Library.

You would turn that off in the settings app - iCloud.

Then once the library is off - choose whether you want the phone to participate in Photo Stream / Photo Sharing or not.

At that point, once iCloud Photo Library is off - you can delete photos from the phone manually on the iOS itself or by connecting to iTunes / Image Capture app / Photos app on Mac / iPhoto on Mac and transferring / deleting photos en masse.

- [How to delete all photos in the camera roll in iOS 8.x?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157011/how-to-delete-all-photos-in-the-camera-roll-in-ios-8-x)
- [Understanding Photo Stream](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100013/understanding-photo-stream)