# How do I delete Voice Memos from my Mac without deleting them from my iCloud?

Tags: storage

I unfortunately own a 256GB Mac and storage is proving to be a huge problem. Once I can afford to buy a new computer, I will. Until then, I have used a tool to identify areas of storage that are largest and it seems over 4GB is being taken up in Application Support for Voice Memos alone.

These are recordings I took on my phone and I very much want to keep; however, I don't even know why they are on my Mac. I want to delete them, without removing them from the Cloud.

Are there any safe ways to do this?

Comment: I edited out your second question as it has been asked on here before ([here’s an older one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/225943/119271)) but if you feel it’s still on topic here, you can always roll back my edits.  If you can’t get a satisfactory answer about the photos from searching, feel free to post a new question.  Oh, and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off iCloud Voice memos by going to
Apple menu  > System Settings, click your name, click iCloud on the right, then click Options next to iCloud Drive. Select Voice Memos in the list of apps to turn it off. Then click Done. You can now go into the voice memos app and safely delete all your recording from just your Mac.